# Stringify JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, object, stringify

I'm looking to stringify an object.

### I want in output like this

```
{"1":{"valeur":"dalebrun","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-20 16:41:50"}, "2": {"valeur":"test","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-20 16:41:50"}}
```

### But I get this

```
{"valeur":"dalebrun","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-20 16:41:50"}, {"valeur":"test","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-20 16:41:50"}
```

### What I do

```
var objVal = {}; //value....
var data = {}; //other value....
var object = $.extend({}, objVal, data); //concat the object 
JSON.stringify(object);
```

Comment: you have `var date` and later you use `data`?

Comment: oups sorry it's data not date

Comment: I can think of no better use case for vote to close a question as being unclear, as when you provide an answer to the OP as I did, and they say it works but it's not what they're looking for

Comment: The answer of Giovanni was the closest answer. But thank you for your help and time @George Jempty. I did not say that you did not do a OP answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution !

I do an for loop on the object. And I iterate on each element in the object. Thank you for your help. The answer of @Giovanni help me to found the solution.

#### Solution:

```
var data = {}; //values....
var objVal = {}; //other values....
var final = {};
var index = 1;
for(var key in data)
{
    final[index] = data[key];
    index = index + 1;
}
final[index] = objVal;
JSON.stringify(final);
```

#### And the output is :

```
{"1":{"valeur":"dfgdfg","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-23 10:36:54"},"2":{"valeur":"uuuuuuuuuu","commentaire":"defg","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-23 10:37:26"},"3":{"valeur":"uuuuuuuuuu","commentaire":"yesssss","usager":"experttasp","date":"2013-08-23 10:38:38"}}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you concat the object, you get an array; you want a map with two elements, using the id "1" and "2"

```
var objVal = {};   //value....
var data = {};     //other value....

var object = {}
object["1"] = objVal;
object["2"] = date;
JSON.stringify(object);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I will have more than one object so it will be "1":.... "2":..... "3": ......  ....   ...

Comment: then use a while/for loop Dave.in your question it looks like as you just have one object.

Comment: If your object are stored in an array (or are somehow iterable) you can use a cycle to put the values in the "object" map.

Comment: I'm trying something with a loop like : var data = {}; var objVal = {}; for(var i in data) { var object = {}; object[i] = $.extend({}, objVal, data);} JSON.stringify(object); // but it doesn't work :(

Comment: While a while loop is certainly possible, see my answer for an underscore based solution